# How to convert bitmap image to base64 without losing image quality android

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, base64

```
    ivPersonImageA.setOnClickListener {
        val mIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(
            mIntent,
            PERSON_CODE
        )
    }


@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override  fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == PERSON_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val  imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            personAvImageA.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
            mPesrsonBase64 = encodeImage(imageBitmap)
            Log.e("mPersonBase64", mPesrsonBase64)
        }
    }
}




private fun encodeImage(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
    val previewWidth = 150
    val previewHeight = bitmap.height * previewWidth / bitmap.width
    val previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth, previewHeight, false)
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.CRLF)
}
```

This is all my code when I run my code and I checked my run box there I got basee64 path after that check that path on [website](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) but there I lost my image quality and this also same problem with server

Comment: Quality? You get only a small bitmap with get("data"). Just a thumbnail of original image. Is that what you want?

Comment: And from this thumbnail you create a scaled bitmap. Why all the fuss?

Comment: I wanna get good image quality

Comment: oo Please tell me what I do how to solve this problem

Comment: You scale down your image to a width of 150 pixels and set JPEG quality to 70 and then wonder about the bad quality. Why do you scale it down then? If you want the size, but better quality, set the JPEG quality to a higher value, eg. 90 or even 100 (less compression, better quality). If you want larger size, don't scale it down at all or at least less.

Comment: You should take a normal picture. Not only a thumbnail. How to change your intent is lesson one in Android programming. You can find hundred examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original bitmap is the pure image data, and you can convert that to (a lot of) Base64 with no loss - it's just another way of representing the same data. But resizing the bitmap is throwing away data, and so is compressing it to JPEG (especially at 70% quality).

You're calling that smaller version *preview* anyway, are you sure that's the data you care about? Previews are usually smaller/less detailed, that's the point! Honestly you probably just either use a much higher quality level for the JPEG compression (90 or 95) or better yet, use `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` if you can. That's a lossless format, and it'll have better quality especially on non-photographic content - the file size will be bigger, but for such a small image it probably won't make much difference.

**Also** you're calling `createScaledBitmap` with filtering set to *false*. Filtering is what blends the pixels to resize things with better quality, it's especially important for shrinking things down at an arbitrary ratio. Set that to *true* and it'll look a lot better.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth, previewHeight, true)
```